# How to align two images at the centre of HTML, on top of each other?

Tags: html, css

I want to align the two images, the moon and the logo. I want all 4 moon images to be above the logo. And I want all the images to be at centre of the page. I think my code is completely wrong, if someone could help me with scratch or even with the existing code. Thank you!

Here the HTML code:

```
   <section id="home" class="home-particles">

         <div id="header">
                   <img class="floating" src="images/moon.png">
                    <img class="floating" src="images/moon.png">
                    <img class="floating" src="images/moon.png">
                    <img class="floating" src="images/moon.png">
                    <img src="images/header.png"/>
        </div> <!-- /header -->
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#home {
    background: #020507;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 800px;
    z-index: 600;
    position: relative;
}

#home.home-particles {
    background: #000000;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#home.home-particles .pg-canvas {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100% !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    opacity: 1;
}
#home.home-particles .shadow-overlay {
    display: none;
}

#header {
    position:relative;
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
}
#header img {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    margin:auto;
}
```

Comment: Wrap the moons on a div, it will keep them separated from the header image and on top of it and then center them using text-align center

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow HiranyaGarbh here is what your issue seems to be.

```
#header img {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    margin:auto;
}
```

is controlling all of the images within the #header tag. This includes your four moon images and your header.png.  The code you have positions all of them right on top of one another.  From what you described you want your header.png to stay where it is and move the moon images just above that.  In order to do that you would need to name each moon picture something unique (assign either a class or ID to each) then give it its own unique position.  You can use the positioning you have above to keep your header.png in the same location but you might want to give it a unique name as well and position it using the position CSS you have above. So it might look something like this.

```
<div id="header">
  <img id="moon1" class="floating" src="images/moon.png">
  <img id="moon2" class="floating" src="images/moon.png">
  <img id="moon3" class="floating" src="images/moon.png">
  <img id="moon4" class="floating" src="images/moon.png">
  <img id="main-img" src="images/header.png"/>
</div>

#main-img {
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  margin:auto;
}

#moon1 {
  unique positioning here...
}

#moon2 {
  unique positioning here...
}

#moon3 {
  unique positioning here...
}

#moon4 {
  unique positioning here...
}

#main-img, #moon1, #moon2, #moon3, #moon4 {
  position: absolute;
}
```

I know this is not a perfect answer but it should get you started.  Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! This helped me somewhat

Comment: You are very welcome, let me know if you have anymore questions.

Answer (score 0):

Position absolute is making all images to be on top of each other.

I recommend separating the moon images in a different div and the logo in another one.

```
<div id="header">
         <div class="MOON">
               <img class="floating" src="images/moon.png">
                <img class="floating" src="images/moon.png">
                <img class="floating" src="images/moon.png">
                <img class="floating" src="images/moon.png">
        </div>
        <div class"logo">
                <img src="images/header.png"/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Like that you will have a better way to edit each kind of images.
After that, for the CSS, you just need to add

```
text-align:center
```

To your #header and it will center your images correctly.
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MZZjZX